# Make Evil Mode "s" key behave like Vim

Tags: key-bindings, evil, doom

Doom Emacs' `s` key does not behave like Vim's implementation. In Vim, `s` deletes the character under the cursor and puts you into insert mode whereas Evil Mode performs a search, similar to `f` and `t`.

1. Is this something that can be changed?
2. If not, what was the reasoning behind `s` not working like it does in Vim? It
   seems like most bindings work as expected, except for this one.

Comment: This is not the behavior of Evil mode. I'm guessing doom has changed its binding. While under `evil-normal-state`, what is the output of `C-h k` for `s`?

Comment: Thanks for this. I wasn't aware that I could look up the mapping so easily. It's mapped to using [evil-snipe](https://github.com/hlissner/evil-snipe).

Answer (score 1):

Having this is your init file will make `s` function as it does in Vim:

`(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "s") 'evil-substitute)`

But this will *replace* the current functionality of `s`, so you will have to map its current value (`C-h k s`) to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Running `C-h k` for `s` revealed that [evil-snipe](https://github.com/hlissner/evil-snipe) was mapped to `s` and `S`.

I found a Doom-specific solution, provided by the creator to add to `config.el` which allows for all evil-snipe functionality to remain the same:

```
(after! evil-snipe
  (evil-snipe-mode -1))
```

Source: https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/1642#issuecomment-518711170